# Convert binary to int

Tags: c#

I want to convert my text into binary and to XOR it with some value, but i get an error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Text.StringBuilder' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

My code is:

```
        public static string StringToBinary(string data)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (char c in data.ToCharArray())
            {
                sb.Append(Convert.ToString(c, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
            }
            var abc = Convert.ToInt32(sb);
            var k = abc ^ 210;
            return k.ToString();

        }
```

Looks like I can't convert binary to int. Is there other way to do this?

Comment: On which line exactly?

Comment: Others have answered correctly to get the value converted.  The exception is occuring because a `StringBuilder` is not a `string`.  You can use `sb.ToString()` to get your string value out, but as others have said that is not necessary.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(object)` requires that the parameter is convertible to Int32. StringBuilder is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have an integer value on this `data` string, you can try using `Convert` class, where you can pass the base you want to convert. Binary is base `2`, so, try this:

```
public static string StringToBinary(string data)
{
   int result = Convert.ToInt32(data, 2);

   return result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I get an error: System.FormatException: Could not find any recognizable digits.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use in-built method. You can just pass the `base` as `2` in `Convert.ToInt32` function.

```
int outputAsInt = Convert.ToInt32(data, 2);
```

or if you want to have the output in a string then simply use .ToString() function.

```
string outputAsString = Convert.ToInt32(data, 2).ToString();
```